# Possible to add workstation to domain from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface

Is there a way to add a XP workstation to a domain via the command line, rather than through My Computer Properties?

If this can't be done from the command line, is there any other simple way (a script) of doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MS article they suggest:

```
netdom join ComputerName /domain:DomainName /userd:User /passwordd:UserPassword
```

The other good options is if you're installing you can always add these options to the installers answer file.

Answer (score 0):

[This Microsoft Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315273/EN-US/) describes joining computers to the domain via command line or script.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out using [Sysprep](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577) for fresh installs. I've had good results with it.